# Multiply in update subquery select

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a table based on 2 select subquery that will be multipied to produce the value for Harga column

here is my code :

```
UPDATE bahanmakanan 
SET Harga = (SELECT HargaSatuan from detail_bahanmakanan 
    WHERE IDBahanMakanan = "BM01")* (SELECT jumlah from bahanmakanan 
    WHERE IDBahanMakanan = "BM01")

WHERE IDBahanMakanan = "BM01" ;
```

The error message return

```
Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'bahanmakanan' for update in FROM clause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do this using `JOIN`,

```
UPDATE  bahanmakanan a
        INNER JOIN detail_bahanmakanan b
            ON a.IDBahanMakanan = b.IDBahanMakanan 
SET     a.Harga = a.jumlah * b.HargaSatuan 
WHERE   a.IDBahanMakanan  = 'BM01'
```

*Please do backup first your database before executing the statement.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE bahanmakanan as t1
JOIN detail_bahanmakanan as t2 USING(IDBahanMakanan)
SET t1.Harga = t2.HargaSatuan * t1.jumlah
WHERE IDBahanMakanan = "BM01";
```